# Should I change the version of android application which has only updated admob ads in it?

Tags: android

I want to know that do I have to change the version of android application.The only change made in the application is integration of admob ads..Please help with your suggestions.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion version numbers should always be changed no matter how minor the code. For example, version numbers are quite often in the format of `1.0.0.0` which would be the main version number, followed by the minor version number, followed by the bug number, followed by the revision number.

Each number should be changed accordingly, for example, if the update is a big change which adds extra functionality, change 1 to 2. For your example of just the admob integration I would probably update the revision number to become 1.0.0.1.